Error creating LVM - create storage failed: command '/sbin/pvs --
How to work around this error (when trying to make an LVM):

create storage failed: command '/sbin/pvs --separator : --noheadings
--units k --unbuffered --nosuffix --options pv_name,pv_size,vg_name,pv_uuid
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36589cfc000000f92915fcd719135fe85' failed: exit
code 5 (500)



Here are the contents of /etc/pve/storage.cfg
root@pve:~# cat /etc/pve/storage.cfg
dir: local
        path /var/lib/vz
        content vztmpl,backup,images,iso
        shared 0

lvmthin: local-lvm
        thinpool data
        vgname pve
        content images,rootdir

cifs: truenas_hpz4g4
        path /mnt/pve/truenas_hpz4g4
        server 192.168.2.223
        share media
        content images
        prune-backups keep-all=1
        username Kerby

cifs: truenas_proxmox_hpml350
        path /mnt/pve/truenas_proxmox_hpml350
        server 192.168.2.105
        share vm
        content images,rootdir
        prune-backups keep-all=1
        username samba

iscsi: Proxmox-TrueNAS-ISCI
        portal 192.168.10.14
        target iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:proxmox-truenas-iscsi-1tb
        content none


You probably have to make the "base storage" (or "base volume"; I don't really grok this GUI; /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36589cfc000000f92915fcd719135fe85, to be precise) a PV first?
